# adding new arifacts to archiva

Tags: maven-2, repository, archiva

I'm using Archiva as my repository manager. It is setup so the users hit the archiva repo and if it doesn't hvae it, the archiva repo will then check the maven central repo (the internal repo proxies the maven central). Now if I want to add a new dependency to the archiva repository, is there a command I can run to tell it to go fetch it from the maven central repo or do I need to manually upload it?

thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Ooh, Archiva looks cool. Thanks for the tip... can't answer your question, though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Archiva will fetch dependencies on demand, there's not way to tell it to apart from building something that requests it.  Just make sure you've set the correct 'Proxy Connector', that had me stumped for a while.

If your dependencies they are not in maven central you either have to manually upload it through the Archiva web interface, or you can use `mvn deploy` on the command line.  You'll have to check how to specify the remote repo with the latter, I can't remember off the top of my head.